# How do I update DateTime in a table row based off of many other tables SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to be able to update a time value in a row in one table based off of many other tables. This time will only change if one of the other tables rows that has the same ID as the row in the main table changes.

I am using Entity Framework with C#

I'm not sure if this can be done with Change Tracking, Triggers, RowVersion or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I would add audit columns to your tables:

```
LastUpdatedDate
CreatedDate
```

You can then maintain these columns and check their values for your needs

Comment: The answer to the following question shows how to keep the LastUpdated column up to date.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522982/t-sql-trigger-update

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what i'm looking for I want this to be a light weight way to update a time field in rows of one table. Im using entity framework