# Auto increment SQL column

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I have to create a new table in my SQL Server 2008 and set my date column to auto increment by 1 day from `Getdate()`.

The first entry should insert using the current date, the second entry should use tomorrow's date and the third entry the day after tomorrow's date and so on.

And I also want to know if there is any way to do this manually with update command that it put today's date in 1st column and tomorrows in 2nd.

Comment: Are you saying that each time a row is inserted into your table the date column has to be incremented based on the date in the most recently inserted row previous to the new row?  OR are you saying you need to generate data for this new table and you'll be inserting multiple rows at one time?

Comment: Yes,each time a row is inserted into table the date column should increment by 1 day  to previous record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer in a simple script:

```
update  t2 
set     DateColumn = DATEADD(day, rn-1, '1970-01-01')
from    @t2 t2
join    (
        select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
        ,       id
        from    @t2 
        ) t2_numbered
on      t2_numbered.id = t2.id

select * from @t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of exactly what you need to do, this function will allow you to do the date incrementing.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Example for generating a date one day in the future:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE());
```

**

1)  If you need to generate an incremented date on each row insert, you could certainly use a trigger and do the update at that time.

[Similar question with example of using trigger to do a row update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522982/t-sql-trigger-update)

2)  If you need to generate multiple rows of data and fill the table, you could do your INSERT operation, and follow it with an update to generate the dates.  Knowing nothing of your table structure, perhaps something like this would work:

```
UPDATE T 
SET T.date_col = 
(
  SELECT 
    TOP(1) DATEADD(dd,1,date_col) 
  FROM myTable
  WHERE
    ID = T.ID - 1
)
FROM myTable T
WHERE
  T.date_col IS NULL;
```

Comment: After running your 2nd query it shows n number of rows afftected but date column is still have null values. datatype of my date column is datetime.

Comment: Actually i want a query to update my date column which are null and it must show time interval of 1 day between records. like 1st row = 2014-03-11, 2nd row = 2014-03-12, 3rd row = 2014-03-13.... my datatype of column is datetime.

Comment: My table structure is:   create table WordOfDay
 --(
 --ID int identity (1,1),
 --EngTitle varchar(200),
 --HinTitle nvarchar(400),
 --EngTitleLink varchar(max),
 --[Date]  datetime
 --)

Comment: i have 365 records in all columns of table except date column which has null values.I want to fill up my date column starting by today's date and add 1 day to next row and so on. by running your query, i am getting message 365 rows affected but after running select statement it again shows null values.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because *all* of your date values are NULL. I thought your first insert was going to use GETDATE()?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a logic!

```
insert into myTbl
select Isnull(max(date_column),getdate()) + 1 from myTbl
```

For Update, try this, `abc` is name of actual table

```
;with cte as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by date_col asc) as rno
    ,date_col
 from abc
)
update  cte  set date_col = Dateadd(dd,rno-1,getdate())
 from cte
where cte.date_col is null
```