# Account for multiple rows in temporary inserted table

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that I wrote to keep track of when a row is updated.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[set_updated_on_update] ON [dbo].[Jobs]
FOR Update 
AS
    UPDATE Jobs
    SET Updated = 'true'
    WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
```

I believe, however, that this trigger will have troubles if multiple rows are ever updated at the same time. Is this correct? If so, how can I deal with this scenario?

Comment: Sure is, messed up my tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will cause issues if you update more than one at a time.  The reason it will cause an error is due to this query returning more than one value when you're doing a straight comparison:

```
Select ID From Inserted
```

Here are some alternate queries you can use:

Using a `JOIN`:

```
Update  J
Set     Update = 'true'
From    Jobs        J
Join    inserted    I   On  J.ID = I.ID
```

Using `IN`:

```
Update  Jobs
Set     Updated = 'true'
Where   ID In (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
```

Using `EXISTS`:

```
Update  J
Set     Update = 'true'
From    Jobs    J
Where   Exists 
(
    Select  *
    From    Jobs    I
    Where   I.ID = J.ID
)
```

Comment: Is there any significant difference between the JOIN and IN methods?

Comment: Depends on how much data you have, but likely no.  I'd use `JOIN` over `IN`, personally, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE Jobs SET Update = 'true'
  FROM INSERTED
  WHERE inserted.id=Jobs.id
```

Comment: this works in my trigger as is, @Jeremy leave me alone

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522982/t-sql-trigger-update and tell me if the 14 corrects have a join